# NoReverseMatch at /<url> When rendering form

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django and I am trying to insert data into a table using a Django form, but I am stuck at this error:

**NoReverseMatch at /vinesF/NewVid** 
**Reverse for 'NewVid' not found. 'NewVid' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Here is my view:

```
def NewVid(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = AddVidForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            primaryName = form.cleaned_data['primaryName']
            Origin = form.cleaned_data['Origin']
            PreferredAudience = form.cleaned_data['PreferredAudience']
            Date = form.cleaned_data['Date']
            Link = form.cleaned_data['Link']
            VPath = form.cleaned_data['VPath']
            AddPath = form.cleaned_data['AddPath']

            FreshVid = video(primaryName=primaryName, Origin=Origin, PreferredAudience=PreferredAudience, Date=Date,Link=Link, VPath=VPath, AddPath=AddPath)

            FreshVid.save()

            return HttpResponse("New Video added")
        else:
            return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})
    else:
        form = AddVidForm()
        return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})
```

HTML template code:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'NewVid' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %} <!-- This line inserts a CSRF token. -->
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }} <!-- This line displays lines of the form. -->
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

URL handler:

```
app_name = 'vinesF'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^NewVid$',views.NewVid, name='NewVid'),
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check the answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051118

Answer (score 1):

it could be the code:

```
url(r'^NewVid$',views.NewVid, name='NewVid'),
```

change to:

```
url(r'^NewVid/$',views.NewVid, name='NewVid'),
```

and change:

```
return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})
```

to:

```
return render(request,'vine/NewVid.html', {form:'form'})
```

Comment: I cant seem to see the difference between these two:
and change:

return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})

to:

return render(request,'vine/NewVid.html', {form:'form'})

Comment: By default, Django’s URL solver is case sensitive. In your case, ‘V’ is different.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by doing the followings:
First, I changed my url handler to pull directly from the root as against the app directory:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^vinesF/',include('vinesF.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^NewVid',vinesF.views.NewVid, name='NewVid'),
```

]

And making  corrections in the view, where I mistakenly reversed the parsing:

```
else:
        return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {'form':form})
else:
    form= AddVidForm()
    return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score -1):

In the code formatting, I see that there is no indentation on the second line. However, if this was the mistake, it should give you an indentation error.

```
def NewVid(request):
    if request.POST:
        form= AddVidForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            primaryName= form.cleaned_data['primaryName']
            Origin= form.cleaned_data['Origin']
            PreferredAudience= form.cleaned_data['PreferredAudience']
            Date= form.cleaned_data['Date']
            Link= form.cleaned_data['Link']
            VPath= form.cleaned_data['VPath']
            AddPath= form.cleaned_data['AddPath']

            FreshVid= video(primaryName=primaryName, Origin=Origin, PreferredAudience=PreferredAudience, Date=Date,Link=Link, VPath=VPath, AddPath=AddPath)

            FreshVid.save()

            return HttpResponse("New Video added")
        else:
            return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})
    else:
        form= AddVidForm()
        return render(request,'vine/Newvid.html', {form:'form'})
```

Comment: I believe that's only a formatting issue in the question, otherwise the code would give an `IndentationError` error instead of the error shown in the question.

Comment: I tried recreating the same error with his code and everything works perfectly at this end. Hence I suggested that could be the only thing I found out of place. Adding an edit on the syntax error part so as not misguide the readers in future. Thank you for the correction.
@ORC-1 could you please also include the URLs.py of the project here in the question to check further.

Comment: Here's the url under vines sub folder:                                        app_name ='vinesF'
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^NewVid$',views.NewVid, name='NewVid'),                                      
Here's the Url for the root folder:                                                                             app= 'vinesF'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^vinesF/',include('vinesF.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ] .  this is the address I use: http://127.0.0.1:8000/vinesF/NewVid/