# NoReverseMatch for url in Django template

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /workoutcal/add/2017/11/1/
Reverse for 'add_workout' not found. 'add_workout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Because of this template code:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_workout' date.year date.month date.day %}" method="post">
```

From the urls.py:

```
url(r'^add/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/$', views.AddWorkoutView.as_view(), name = 'add_workout'),
```

I've followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url). Don't know why my URL name isn't found. Any ideas?

EDIT:

The entire urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'workoutcal'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.redirect_to_calendar),
    url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[1-9]|1[0-2])$', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'), #Detail of a workout. Shows lifts, duration, etc. All the attributes.
    url(r'^add/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/$', views.AddWorkoutView.as_view(), name = 'add_workout'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'), #Editing an existing workout. id is id of workout object to edit.
    url(r'^name/$', views.get_contact_form, name='contact_form'),
    url(r'^get_lifts/$', views.get_lifts, name='get_lifts'),
    url(r'^add_lift/$', views.add_lift, name='add_lift'),
    url(r'^get_cardio/$', views.get_cardio, name='get_cardio'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^username/$', views.get_username, name='username'),
]
```

The view that's rendering the template:

```
class AddWorkoutView(View):
    def get(self, request, year=None, month=None, day=None):
        template_name = 'workoutcal/addworkout.html'
        template = loader.get_template(template_name)
        date = datetime(year=int(year), month=int(month), day=int(day))
        context = {
            'date':date,
            'current_name':request.user.username,
            'title':'Add workout',
            'range':range(4),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Are you using a namespace for those URL

Comment: Could you post entire your urls.py file?

Comment: I looked into namespaces and found this: "The url template tag uses the namespace of the currently resolved view as the current application in a RequestContext. You can override this default by setting the current application on the request.current_app attribute.". Since I only have one application in my app, I don't think defining any new namespace is necessary.

Comment: Done, see edit. Also, I should add that the view rendering the template with the url tag is THE SAME as the view pointed to by the url `add_workout`. Maybe this is the problem? Can you reverse the url of the view that is rendering the template (circular url referencing?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you define your urls with a namespace:

```
app_name = 'workoutcal'
```

So you need to include name space in url reverse:

```
<form action="{% url 'workoutcal:add_workout' date.year date.month date.day %}" method="post">
```